# How to put in value for an input with ngmodel selectmode?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I have two inputs with the same ngmodel:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Time Range To:"
               [(ngModel)]="timeRange"
               [selectMode]="'rangeTo'"
               >

<input type="text" placeholder="Time Range To:"
               [(ngModel)]="timeRange"
               [selectMode]="'rangeFrom'"
               >
```

in my ts file, i use

```
public timeRange: Date[];
```

Retrieving the data is no problem by using this.timeRange[0] for example, but I want to put in a value with a button click and when i use this.timeRange[0], I get the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

In my function I try to do this:

```
this.timeRange[0] = new Date(...);
```

How can I put in a value for the rangeTo and rangeFrom inputs?

Comment: Did you initialize `this.timeRange` anywhere? Maybe you should do `public timeRange: Date[] = []`; But are you sure you want it to be an array? Your `ngModel` is trying to set `timeRange` to a text value

Comment: Why are you using same ngModel? It'll overwrite the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using same variable to two input tags, just create an Object of timeRange and add from, to Dates according to your requirement.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Time Range To:" [(ngModel)]="timeRange.to">

<input type="text" placeholder="Time Range To:" [(ngModel)]="timeRange.from">
```

> in component.ts

use interface or an Object type to create variable,  I am using interface here

```
timeRange = new timeRange();

//adding and retrieving is now simple with this

export interface timeRange {
  to?: Date();
  from?: Date();
}
```